# Push Notification issue in Android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using GCM push notification for android with cordova plugin. I have register with two device(SAMSUNG With Version 4.4.2 and Lenovo K3 Note with Version (5.0)) both connecting with WIFI only. But When i Send Notification from my Server SAMSUNG getting all notification but K3 mobile not frequently getting notification. Please suggest how can I troubleshoot this issue and How can i view the app log when app closed in mobile at eclipse or suggest some other tools.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Notification check box is checked]

Go to your app info check that notification check box is checked or not

Comment: It is checked. i am getting a notification but all notification am not getting. But In my server side i am getting response from GCM. But GCM not sending all notification to my K3 Mobile.